# connecting multiple controllers mininet

Tags: sdn, mininet, pox

I want to connect 3 pox controllers on mininet.
Two of the controllers work fine via **forwarding.l2_pairs** but this only connects two of them. I used **forwarding.l2_pairs** and **forwarding.l2_pairs** as well but nothing seems to solve my problem.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be descriptive about your question. Also share any coding attempts you did previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run:

```
$ cd ~/pox
$ ./pox.py forwarding.l2_learning
```

then you should set port for each of them with this command:

```
sudo ~/pox/pox.py openflow.of_01 --port=6636  forwarding.l2_pairs info.packet_dump samples.pretty_log log.level --DEBUG
```